# Для чего нужна инструкция GO в MS SQL и как правильно отделать и использовать пакеты?

Tags: sql-server

Единственное, что я понял -  в отдельные пакеты нужно выносить создание некоторых объектов БД(процедуры, представления, функции итд.)

Но что вообще является пакетом, как их грамотно использовать и когда так не и не понял.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В-принципе, насколько я понял идею команды `GO`.

Мы хотим четко разделить пакеты и как бы сказать сообщить `SQL`, что выполнять скрипт будем с помощью отдельных команд, где предыдущей команде необходимо успешно завершиться для отправки следующей команды

Такие отдельные команды называются `пакетами`

На практике `GO` наоборот "мешает" и лучше его не использовать, но можно выделить несколько причин для использования этой команды

1. Некоторые инструкции (например `USE`) весьма странно работают без `GO` после них. Соответственно, здесь необходимо их использование
2. Синтаксис некоторых инструкций требует того, чтобы она была единственной в `пакете`. Без `GO` ничего просто не запустится
3. `GO` поддерживает параметр `count`, определяющий какое кол-во раз нужно выполнить пакет. Если вам нужно выполнить какой-то `пакет` несколько раз, то можно просто написать инструкции и потом `GO count`